# MySQL selecting multiple relational tables into one row with group_concat

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, group-concat

I have 5 tables: productCategory, products, productOptions, options, optionsGroup.  What I'm trying to do is somehow concat and group them into one query to return one row with all information about one product.  For example, a certain type of food will have different sizes and different flavors; bottles have different sizes and smells.  Here are the tables:

productCategory

```
categoryId    categoryName
1             food
2             freshener
```

product

```
productId    productCategoryRef    productName
1            1                     ....
2            1
3            2
4            2
FK references categoryId
```

productOptions

```
categoryRef  optionsRef
1            1
1            3
2            2
2            4
FK categoryRef references productCategory (categoryId)
FK optionsRef references options (optionsId)
```

options

```
optionsId    optionsName
1            kg
2            ml
3            Flavor
4            Fragrance
```

optionsGroup

```
groupId    groupOptionRef  groupName
1          1               3
2          1               7
3          1               14
4          2               50
5          2               250
6          3               Chicken
7          3               Beef
8          4               Alpine
9          4               Berries
FK groupOptionRef references options (optionId)
```

So a food bag can be 3kg, 7kg or 14kg and can have two different flavors. How can I get all this information in one row in a readable format?  Here's what I tried:

```
SELECT 
  pc.*, p.*, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT o.optionsName) AS optionName, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(og.groupName) AS options 
FROM productCategories pc 
  JOIN products p ON p.productCategoryId=pc.categoryId 
  JOIN productOptions po ON po.categoryRef=pc.categoryId 
  JOIN options o ON o.optionsId=po.optionsRef 
  JOIN optionsGroup og ON og.groupOptionRef=o.optionsId 
WHERE p.productName=:itemName 
  GROUP BY p.productId
```

This gives me one row with

```
....
optionName: 'kg,Flavor',
options: '3,7,14,Chicken,Beef'
....
```

which is a mess.  Is it possible to somehow concat each option together and then post-process it easier without having to guess which part goes to kg/Flavor?

I know it would be easy here but later there will be a review section which will reference this productId which I would like to join as well to this query. Any advice is appreciated, I'm open to a better DB structure if one is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind option names being repeated, you can group_concat a concat like this:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(o.optionsName, ': ', og.groupName) ORDER BY o.optionsName, og.groupName) AS options
```

If you want any more structured than that, you'd have to subquery (grouping by option name, and group_concating it's group names; then grouping without option name in the outer query); but at that point it is definitely worth considering if you should just be handling formatting and grouping the results client side.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that does make it easier to distinguish the categories.  Is this how relational databases work tho? Seems like the whole point is to normalize your tables which would create lots one-to-many relations but there's no way to return a clean result without returning one row for each option, like in my case?

Comment: Yes, this is typical in any one-to-many relationship; an RDBMS' ultimate goal is to make data easy to maintain and retrieve, presentation is a secondary concern. Ideally, your database structure would have separate tables for weight, volume, flavor, and fragrance (those those last two could probably overlap); or perhaps a "sub product" table with fields for each of those properties (perhaps a certain flavor is only available in a 10lb bag).

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that as well, since not every product will necessarily have all options.  Thank you for your help!